# Ember js : save() method does not call PUT

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Hi I am trying to call PUT endpoint but it calls DELETE

Controller :

```
 save: function (channel) {
        //channel.save();
        channel.save();
        this.set('isEditing', false);
    },
```

When I check the network logs, its calls DELETE method not PUT. I know, I can override the call in the model by doing something like this.

```
DS.RESTAdapter.reopen({
    ajaxOptions: function(url, type, hash) {
        hash = hash || {};
        if (type === 'DELETE') {
            hash.data = hash.data || {};
            hash.data['_method'] = type;
            type = 'PUT';
        }
        return this._super(url, type, hash);
    }
});
```

Is there any better way of doing it.

Comment: Are you deleting a record?  If you want it to use a non-standard protocol, you'll need to override and do it like you're doing.

Comment: `save` will call `DELETE` if the record has been deleted. Examine the records' status flags.